# How do Firefox and Chrome render JPEG images on Linux?

Tags: desktop, firefox, graphics, chrome, jpeg

I'm having trouble with Firefox and Chrome for some time now and it's very irritating.

Neither of these browsers will render JPEG images. Konqueror and Opera are fine though.

What libraries I can try swapping or up/downgrading to get this working again?

I'm forced by nVidia to maintain an old driver stack, which could also be contributing to the issue. Can it?

Comment: why are you forced to keep an old driver stack? Also, it's probably a libjpeg problem, not driver-related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak for the official releases, but debian un-branded releases of those applications  ("iceweasel" and "chromium-browser") use the libjpeg*.so library.

Try temporarily moving /usr/lib/libjpeg* somewhere else and see if that breaks firefox or chrome.

however libjpeg does such a good job i'd expect the konqueror based browsers to use it too... More likely the problem you face is at a higher level, libgtk, perhaps.  if you have binutils installed you can use the 'ldd' command to see which .so files are linked